# Get percentile values from column SQL

Tags: sql

0

Let's say I have a table storing users, the number of red balls they have, the total number of balls (blue, yellow, other colors etc.), and the ratio of red to total balls.

Schema looks like this:

```
**user_id** | **ratio** | **red_balls** | **total_balls**
     1            .2             2              10
     2            .3             6              20
```

I want to select the 0, 25, 50, 75, and 100 percentile values based on ordering the red_balls column, so this doesn't mean I want the 0, 0.25, etc. values for the ratio column. I want the 25th percentile of the red_balls column. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add some more rows with sample data, and also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this if you are using sql server

```
SELECT TOP (25) PERCENT red_balls
FROM schema
ORDER BY red_balls DESC
```